# how to use Convert-PemToPfx in Azure automation account?

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault, pem, azure-automation, pfx

Im trying to generate pfx from the pem and key file stored in azure keyvualt from azure powershell automation account. I can generate a pfx with the same key and pem file using openssl but when I try the same in powershell I'm getting an error "Convert-PemToPfx : Exception setting "PrivateKey": "The public key of the certificate does not match the value 
specified."".

```
$secretpem = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '$vaultname' -Name 'secret-pem'
$secretkey = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '$vaultname' -Name 'secret-key'
$pem = "certificate.pem" 
$secretpem.SecretValueText | Out-File -FilePath $pem 
$key = "certificate.key"
$secretkey.SecretValueText | Out-File -FilePath $key
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssW0rD!" -asplaintext -for
#Get-Content -Path certificate.pem
#Get-Content -Path certificate.key
Import-Module -Name PSPKI
Convert-PemToPfx -InputPath certificate.pem -KeyPath certificate.key  -OutputPath certificate.pfx - 
Password $password
```

Comment: Can you run the script on the local machine?

Comment: When I perform the same on a windows VM it says that "exception setting in private key operation is not suuported on this platform"